# How to access textbox's select function in Autocompletebox

Tags: windows-phone-8, textbox, controls, autocompletebox

I am trying to place the cursor at the end of the text in textbox inside Microsoft.Phone.Controls.AutoCompleteBox. 
how can i do this?

It is strange that AutoCompleteBox has Focus function but no function for Select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much explained [on this blog](http://www.learningwindowsphone.com/blog/?p=68)

Basically, it comes down to getting the inner TextBox

```
var textbox = GetTemplateChild("Text") as TextBox;
```

And then from there you can easily do whatever you would otherwise do with a TextBox.